# Import/merge with socialsounddesign.com?

Tags: discussion

http://socialsounddesign.com is another audio recording and production SO-engine-driven site, and it's been around much longer.  It already has a large user base and a lot of questions and answers.  Is there any way the two efforts could be merged?  I don't know who runs social sound design, if it's a commercial endeavor, etc, but it would be nice to get all the Qs and As in one place.

Comment: I like snippets like **Don't forget to up-vote the question or answer if you find...** and **Please note: When commenting on someone's question or answer, you will not receive...**. Useful (and unobtrusive).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Andrew Spitz from SocialSoundDesign.com emailed me his response to this thread since he didn't have the 5 rep required to post on meta.

> On one hand I would love to merge and
>   attempt to be part of the SE 2.0, on
>   the other they made it very
>   unappealing for me to let go what we
>   have built and go towards something
>   that is not a guaranty that we'll even
>   make it though the beta phase. I'm
>   pretty annoyed with SE, as at the
>   beginning they kept changing their
>   ethos and criteria so often that it
>   reached a point where I couldn't keep
>   up anymore and just gave up. Even
>   though SSD has got a really nice
>   community and a relatively big one for
>   this kind of topic, they said I
>   wouldn't be able to do the jump
>   without starting again. Their standard
>   is a general one, not one based on the
>   topic, we don't qualify.
>
> In terms of content I think both our
>   SE sites would fit. Although somewhere
>   down the line, users on SSD mentioned
>   they would prefer not to merge. As you
>   mention, I like that we can keep it
>   looser and do our own thing. As I
>   mentioned before, it's really
>   frustrating when you're with a company
>   that changes their ways everyday. I
>   don't know how fair it is on the users
>   of SSD to move everyone and have them
>   loose their reputation points.
>
> Basically, moving to 2.0 is a gamble -
>   even merging with you guys, which
>   would be a good option. If we decide
>   to move, and don't fit their quota,
>   then we loose everything, and I don't
>   think it's worth the risk. They
>   explicitly said that once we decide to
>   go to 2.0 we can't go back :-( sad.
>
> It's a pity, cause it would be great
>   to be part of the bigger picture.
>   Would love to have the iPhone/iPad
>   app, and the rep points that go from
>   one to the next SE site.
>
> Please understand that it's not your
>   SE site the problem, but the jump to
>   2.0. I hope you guys make it past the beta, but if you don't, you have a
>   home with SSD!

Answer (score 9):

I think this is similar to [this discussion](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/q/64/64) on DJ questions.  SocialSoundDesign has some hardware, software, and engineering questions that would be on topic here, but their focus seems to be more on the artistic and creative aspects of sound design.

Another thing I noticed is that their community seems a little looser than most StackExchange sites.  Questions that would be closed here are answered and upvoted on SocialSoundDesign.  Some examples (just from the first page of questions):

- Assembling my first recording package. What to buy?
- Your most interesting recording of 2010
- A good read for Xmas holidays!

So my opinion is that there may be opportunities for referrals between the two sites but I don't think they're similar enough for a merge to work.  Regardless, I emailed Andrew Spitz who runs the site and linked him to this discussion so we'll see if he has any input.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a SE 1.0 site. If they're open to migrating to SE 2.0 and being merged with this site, I have no problem with it. But this audio.se has very little in the way of questions yet.

They've been around since February. Just a guess, but I think it more likely they'd want to be migrated to 2.0 and questions here would be merged with their content; that's what I'd want if I were a member of a community that had been around for a while.